# But how to prove that $int(X) \subset int(int(X))$?

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove that, for every set $X \subset \mathbb{R^m}$, int(X)=int(int(X))? (In other words, int(X) is an open set).

It is clear for me that $int(int(X)) \subset int(X)$. But how to prove that $int(X) \subset int(int(X))$?

Comment: Make a smaller $\epsilon$ ball.

Comment: You have said you know that $\mathrm{int}(X)$ is open. So, if $U$ is open what set is $\mathrm{int}(U)?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T = \operatorname{int} X$. We need to show for every $x \in T$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ s.t. $\forall y\in B(x;\epsilon)$ in an interior point of  $X$.

Let $x \in T$, there exists $r > 0$ s.t. $B(x;r) \subset S$. let $y\in B(x;r)$, set $\epsilon= r-d(x,y)>0$ . We show $B(y;\epsilon) \subset B(x;r) \subset S$. If you can show it, $y \in T$

$z \in B(y;\epsilon)$, i.e. $d(y,z)<\epsilon$, then $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)<r$

Answer (score 1):

Int(X) = $\underset{D \hspace{2pt} open}{\underset{D \subseteq X}{\cup}} D$.  In every topological space,  the union of any collection of open sets is an open set. So, int (X) is open.